# Importing JSON file for custom role in Azure AD

Tags: json, azure, azure-active-directory

Trying to import a JSON file for creating an Azure custom role with the following content

```
{
    "Name": "Veeam Backup for Microsoft Azure v4 Service Account Permissions",
    "Id:": null 
    "IsCustom": true,
    "Description": "Permissions needed to function Veeam Backup for Microsoft Azure v4",
    "Actions": [
      "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/read",
      "Microsoft.Authorization/*/Write",
      "Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard/read",
      "Microsoft.Compute/disks/beginGetAccess/action",
      "Microsoft.Compute/disks/delete",
      "Microsoft.Compute/disks/endGetAccess/action",
      "Microsoft.Compute/disks/read",
      "Microsoft.Compute/disks/write",
      "Microsoft.Compute/snapshots/beginGetAccess/action",
      "Microsoft.Compute/snapshots/delete",
      "Microsoft.Compute/snapshots/endGetAccess/action",
      "Microsoft.Compute/snapshots/read",
      "Microsoft.Compute/snapshots/write",
      "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/deallocate/action",
      "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/delete",
      "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/read",
      "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/write",
      "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read",
      "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/runCommand/action",
      "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action",
      "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write",
      "Microsoft.DevTestLab/Schedules/write",
      "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/delete",
      "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/join/action",
      "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/read",
      "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/write",
      "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/join/action",
      "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/read",
      "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/join/action",
      "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/read",
      "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/delete",
      "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/write",
      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/read",
      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",
      "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/write",
      "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/moveResources/action",
      "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/delete",
      "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read",
      "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/write",
      "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/authorizationRules/ListKeys/action",
      "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/authorizationRules/read",
      "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/authorizationRules/write",
      "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/delete",
      "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/read",
      "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues/write",
      "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/read",
      "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/write",
      "Microsoft.ServiceBus/register/action",
      "Microsoft.Sql/locations/*",
      "Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/databases/delete",
      "Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/databases/read",
      "Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/databases/write",
      "Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/encryptionProtector/read",
      "Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/read",
      "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/azureAsyncOperation/read",
      "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/read",
      "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/transparentDataEncryption/read",
      "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/usages/read",
      "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/write",
      "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/delete",
      "Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticPools/read",
      "Microsoft.Sql/servers/read",
      "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/read",
      "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listKeys/action",
      "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/managementPolicies/write",
      "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/read",
      "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/write",
      "Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/write",
      "Microsoft.Sql/servers/encryptionProtector/read",
      "Microsoft.Compute/diskEncryptionSets/read",
      "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/read",
      "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys/versions/read",
      "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/deploy/action",
      "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/syncGroups/read"
    ],
    "NotActions": [],
    "DataActions": [
      "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys/read",
      "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys/encrypt/action",
      "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys/decrypt/action"
    ],
    "NotDataActions": [],
    "AssignableScopes": [
      "/subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
    ]
  }
```

results in the following error message:
Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
For import I used this command:
New-AzRoleDefinition -InputFile "/home/christian/VBAZv4_CustomRole.json"

I'm quite sure that I have sufficient permission to import.

Any idea, why I'm not able to import the JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

To Create and assign a custom role in Azure Active Directory you require the following:

- Azure AD Premium P1 or P2 license
- Privileged Role Administrator or Global Administrator
- AzureADPreview module when using PowerShell
- Admin consent when using Graph explorer for Microsoft Graph API

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-create#prerequisites

Hope this helps!